# header's constroctor ending before it should

Tags: c++

For some reason my, makefile will not compile. The error it is talking about is in my header.

```
 Alignment.hh:34:22 error: expected ')' before '&' token
```

The calls are supposed to be using the references, which I have in when I call this function.

This is my Alignment.hh file

```
#ifndef encod
#define encod
class Encoded        
 { private:
    Direct &origin;  
    char *subinsertion; 
    int subinsertlen;  
    struct Edit *operation;
    int editnum;    
    string dname; 
    int dlength;      
    int gaplen;
   public:
    Encoded(Alignment &obj); 
    ~Encoded();              
    int getEditNum() const;  
    struct Edit* getOperation() const; 
    int getSubInsertLen() const;
    char* getSubInsertion() const;;
    int getDLength() const; 
    string getDName() const; 
    Direct& getOrigin() const; 
    string toString() const; 
    char* getDSeq() const;  
    int getNumDiff();
    bool operator<=(Encoded &rightobj)const;
 };

 class Compressed : public Encoded {
     private:
        Encoded encode;
     public:
        Compressed(Alignment &obj);
        bool operator <=(Encoded &rightobj) const;
};
#endif
```

Comment: You haven't declared `Direct` or `Alignment`.

Comment: `class Direct;` add a forward declaration

Answer (score -1):

Try to compile this

```
#ifndef encod
#define encod
class Direct;
class Alignment;
class Encoded        
 { private:
    Direct &origin;  
    char *subinsertion; 
    int subinsertlen;  
    struct Edit *operation;
    int editnum;    
    string dname; 
    int dlength;      
    int gaplen;
   public:
    Encoded(Alignment &obj); 
    ~Encoded();              
    int getEditNum() const;  
    struct Edit* getOperation() const; 
    int getSubInsertLen() const;
    char* getSubInsertion() const;;
    int getDLength() const; 
    string getDName() const; 
    Direct& getOrigin() const; 
    string toString() const; 
    char* getDSeq() const;  
    int getNumDiff();
    bool operator<=(Encoded &rightobj)const;
 };

 class Compressed : public Encoded {
     private:
        Encoded encode;
     public:
        Compressed(Alignment &obj);
        bool operator <=(Encoded &rightobj) const;
};
#endif
```

Comment: no description problem<->solution, how is OP supposed to learn from an answer like this?